# How to register user and maintain in-app-purchase state on my server

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'd like to have a user register with email and password so that I can provide his in app purchase in my android app / web site and PC software. (Its a download from my server)

1A) Would you force the user to register?

Or 1B) Allow him to skip registration if he wants and the purchase will only work on Apple devices.

And 2) How would you prevent someone from re-registering multiple emails on the same device through Apple's restore purchase feature and then allowing their friends to sign in with those emails and get things for free?

EDIT - In 2) I hear all the time people say store the receipt on the server and then check it, but I've never seen code. Also when you restore purchases the receipt is not the same so I'm not sure how you'd know to prevent the user from registering multiple emails across restores purchases. I'm looking for code(pseudo?) from anyone who has implemented receipt checking on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would go with B and let them choose. After all, if they aren't going to use the Android, web nor PC versions, why should they have to give you their email address?
2. Personally, I wouldn't stop people from re-registering with multiple email addresses. Yes, some people will take advantage of it, but at the end of the day, most of those people would not otherwise have paid for it, so you haven't really lost sales. See http://torrentfreak.com/piracy-is-theft-ridiculous-lost-sales-they-dont-exist-says-minecraft-creator-110303/ for more information.

Comment: 1) Of course then you have to deal with people who are going to be pissed that they have to pay twice when they realize how cool the web/PC interface is.

Comment: But then why not let them register and therefore activate their purchase for the web at a later date?

Comment: Then those who haven't legitimately purchased will be able to register defeating the purpose of registering in the first place. If I can verify the receipt as per the question the problem goes away.

Comment: My point is, only a small fraction of people will bypass purchasing. Spend the time improving your service rather than trying to fight the never-ending battle against piracy.